# Obtaining numbers from strings

Tags: string, vb.net, text, numbers

I am very new to programming with Visual Basic. I am opening a text file using vb.net. I currently have a program that reads the text file line by line and adds each line into an array.

```
 Private Function Read_GCode() As ArrayList
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
    Dim TextLine As New ArrayList
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine.Add(objReader.ReadLine())
    Loop
    Return TextLine
End Function
```

My text file will have something like this

> (* SHAPE Nr: 0 *)
>
> G0 X2999.948 Y1771.567
>
> M3 M8
>
> G0 Z   0.000
>
> G1 Z   0.000
>
> F400
>
> G1 X2999.948 Y 771.567
>
> F0
>
> G1 Z   0.000
>
> G0 Z   0.000
>
> M9 M5
>
> G0 X   0.000 Y   0.000
>
> M2 (Program end)

The next step is to write a function to obtain the numbers from each line. Only the lines starting with "G" will be required. How do I extract the numbers from the string?

Comment: You want to extract all the numbers containing in a **text file** and show them on a form OR in a console application?

Comment: Are all the lines in the text file similar? Post a bit more of the text file's content.

Comment: No. I'm iterating through each line of the text file because each line has a different meaning and I need to assign different variables to the numbers. Like in the example I will need to get the number 2999.948 and assign it to the variable x1 and 771.567 into the variable y1.

Comment: Post more lines from the text file for more clarity.

Comment: Added more contents of the text file.

Comment: `Regex.Matches()`: `G\d+\s+X\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*Y\s*((?1))` -> `X = decimal.Parse([Match].Group(1))`, `Y = decimal.Parse([Match].Group(2))`

Comment: If this is a [G-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) (NC-code) source file (as it looks like one), you should probably use a dedicated library to import these files.

Comment: Yes this is G code. So far I did not found any library to import the G code. Hence, I am trying to write a code to read the data from the G code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this quick hack

```
Dim decList As New List(Of Decimal)
Dim tmp1 As Integer
Dim str As String = "G0 X2999.948 Y1771.567"
Dim started As Boolean = False
Dim result As String = ""
For i As Integer = 0 To str.Length() - 1
    If (started) Then
        If (Integer.TryParse(CStr(str(i)), tmp1) Or CStr(str(i)) = ".") Then
            result &= str(i)
        Else
            started = False
            decList.Add(Decimal.Parse(result))
            result = ""
        End If
    Else
        started = True
        If(Integer.TryParse(CStr(str(i)), tmp1) Then
            result &= str(i)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The above code should return `2999.948` and `1771.567` in `decList`.

Comment: What should I do if I want both the numbers to be in separated variables instead of a list?

Comment: Simply do `Dim I As Decimal = decList(0)` and `Dim j As Decimal = decList(1)`.

Comment: `tmp1` is for a temporary storage of the output from  `Integer.TryParse`.

Comment: I tried the code and `decList` only has `0` and `2999.948` in it. It seems to stop after the first and second number. At least that's what I found after manipulating the text.

Answer (score 0):

To read the text file you can use `File.ReadAllLines` which will return an array of lines. To parse the lines I used various `String` methods and added properties to a `GData` objects. Finally the result is displayed in a in `DataGridView`.

```
Private GDataList As New List(Of GData)
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("G Code.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        If line.StartsWith("G") Then
            GDataList.Add(ParseG(line))
        End If
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = GDataList
End Sub

Private Function ParseG(input As String) As GData
    Dim g As New GData
    Dim words = input.Split(" "c)
    Dim NextWordIndex As Integer
    g.GValue = CInt(words(0).Trim("G"c))
    If words(1).StartsWith("X") Then
        If words(1).Length > 1 Then
            g.XValue = CDbl(words(1).Trim("X"c))
            NextWordIndex = 2
        Else
            g.XValue = CDbl(words(2))
            NextWordIndex = 3
        End If
        If words(NextWordIndex).StartsWith("Y") Then
            If words(NextWordIndex).Length > 1 Then
                g.YValue = CDbl(words(NextWordIndex).Trim("Y"c))
            Else
                g.YValue = CDbl(words(NextWordIndex + 1))
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf words(1).StartsWith("Z") Then
        If words(1).Length > 1 Then
            g.ZValue = CDbl(words(1).Trim("Z"c))
        Else
            g.ZValue = CDbl(words(2))
        End If
    End If
    Return g
End Function

Public Class GData
    Public Property GValue As Integer
    Public Property XValue As Double
    Public Property YValue As Double
    Public Property ZValue As Double
End Class
```

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.'
I got this error. I think it's caused by spaces. How do I handle spaces with the function?

Comment: I tested on the sample text file you provided. You could string methods can be chained. You can add another `.Trim()`. The empty parenthesis will trim a space from the beginning of end of the string.